# How can i quote escape characters in csv writer in python

Tags: python, csv

I am writing the csv file like this

```
for a in products:
    mylist =[]
    for h in headers['product']:
        mylist.append(a.get(h))
        writer.writerow(mylist)
```

My my few fields are text fields can conatins any characters like `,` `"` `'` `\n` or anything else. what is the safest way to write that in csv file. also file will also have integers and floats

Comment: This already works, are you actually having a problem?

Comment: It is currently working but didn't knew whwther it will work on all sort of weird data , people will enter. should i use QUOTE_ALL , MINIMAL , NON NUMERIC OR WHAT

Answer (score 14):

You should use **QUOTE_ALL** quoting option:

```
import StringIO
import csv

row = ["AAA \n BBB ,222 \n CCC;DDD \" EEE ' FFF 111"]

output = StringIO.StringIO()
wr = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow( row )

# Test:
contents = output.getvalue()
parsedRow = list(csv.reader([contents]))[0]

if parsedRow == row: print "BINGO!"
```

Comment: This is awesome! I didn't know about `StringIO` to create an "in-memory file". Import should be: `from io import StringIO`

Comment: There's also [`csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) which quotes only when problematic characters are present in a field.

Answer (score 5):

using csv.QUOTE_ALL will ensure that all of your entries are quoted like so:
`"value1","value2","value3"` while using csv.QUOTE_NONE will give you: `value1,value2,value3`

Additionally, this will change all of your quotes in the entries to double quotes as follows. `"somedata"user"somemoredata` will become
`"somedata""user""somemoredata` in your written .csv

However, if you set your quotechar to the backslash character (for example), your entry will return as " for all quotes.

```py
create=csv.writer(open("test.csv","wb"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\', quotechar='"')
for element in file:
    create.writerow(element)
```

and the previous example will become `somedata\"user\"somemoredata` which is clean. It will also escape any commas that you have in your elements the same way.

Comment: you say "if you set your quotechar to the backslash character" but in your example you set quotechar to ". While setting escapechar to \. Which one is correct? Also, what should I do to get "{\"value\": \"value\"}" ? QUOTE_NONE will remove the " around my json which is a problem.